# Calculation CRC32 by Srecord

Tags: makefile, bin, crc32

I have to calculate CRC32 from .bin file. I should use Srecord.
I have added follow line to post build section in my makefile.

```
../srec_cat "app.bin" -binary -crc32-l-e -max -o "app.crc.bin" -binary
```

Unfortunately I have got error like this:

```
: 0x3814: multiple 0x00000000 values
(previous = 0x53, this one = 0x00)
make[1]: *** [post-build] Error 1
```

I was looking for solution of my problem, but i didn't find correct way.

If I give 0x3814 instead of "-max", any problem doesn't occur. I don't want give size bin file during every compilation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `-max`?

Comment: -max describes size of binary file.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this parameter?

Comment: http://srecord.sourceforge.net/srecord-1.64.pdf 
-max is equivalent for -MAximum-Address

Comment: If this is an equivalent, then an input specification must go afterwards:`srec_cat in.srec -offset - -maximum-addr in.srec`.